# Define a trim method on Array that removes the first and last element

Tags: arrays, ruby, methods

```
class Array
define_method(:trim) do
new_array = self.pop()
new_array = self.shift()
end
end
```

EDIT: What I tried (among other things)

["hi", "ho", "he"].trim()

This returns "hi".

Remove the last element. Remove the first element. But how do I get the method to return the remaining array instead of what's returned by .shift (or whatever happens to be the last instruction of the method)? Do I need another variable?

Thank you.

Comment: There's no need for `define_method`, just use `def trim`

Answer (score 3):

`pop() and shift()` will modify the array directly. You just need to tell the method to return self

```
class Array
    define_method(:trim) do
      self.pop()
      self.shift()
      self
    end
end
```

EDIT : as this method can be dangerous, I suggest you define both `trim!` and `trim`. Where `trim!` will modify the array directly and `trim` return a copy of the array, trimmed

```
class Array
    def trim!
      self.pop()
      self.shift()
      self
    end

    def trim
      self.dup.trim!
    end
end
```

Comment: You can omit `self.` and `()`, i.e. you can write `pop` instead of `self.pop()`

Comment: This is an excellent answer Cyril. I was working on the same problem and it really helped. What you did that was MUCH different than the avg SO guy is that you understood that @Yalla Papi was working with .pop() and .shift() and you included them in your answer, vs szymek's answer which used more advanced techniques that didn't help. I wish more answerers responded as you did here.

Comment: @stefan Thanks!!! This is really good to know. The problem works even with your tweak.

Answer (score 3):

You can use range when accessing array elements, like that

```rb
ary = [1, 2, 3, 4]; ary[1..-2] #=> [2, 3]
```

So going back to the method, it can be:

```rb
class Array
  def trim
    self[1..-2]
  end
end
```

[EDIT]: to avoid returning `nil` for empty arrays:

```
class Array
  def trim
    self[1..-2] || []
  end
end
```

Comment: This is how I'd do it, too.

Comment: This returns `nil` for an empty array, i.e. `[].trim #-> nil`

Comment: Yeah, I'd probably just put a guard clause in front like `return self if self.empty?`

Comment: @Stefan you are right, can get away with an early return `return [] if empty?`,  cast or use Cyril's answer.